# Google Maps API Key is Not Working When Application Restrictions Set to Website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-geocoding-api

I'm Using Maps Javascript API & Geocoding API on My Angular Application Which is Hosted on Microsoft Powerappsportals. So, Map Is Displaying as Long as Application Restriction is None. But When I Change Application Restriction to Website It Always Stopped Working.

Getting Following Error Only When Setting Restriction to Website Otherwise It was Working Perfectly Fine

```
{
  error_message: "API keys with referer restrictions cannot be used with this API."
  results: []
  status: "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

My Application Is Deployed on Domain Like  `https://test-abc.powerappsportals.com` and I've Tried to Add These Following URLs in Website Restrictions

```
test-abc.powerappsportals.com/*
*.powerappsportals.com/*
powerappsportals.com/*
https://test-abc.powerappsportals.com/*
https://*.powerappsportals.com/*
https://powerappsportals.com/*
```

But Nothing Worked for Me It's Only Working When Application Restriction is None. So Help Me If Anyone Got The Similar Issue Thankyou.

Comment: But Still No Solution Found, That's Why Posted Here.

Comment: You can't use web services with the referrer restrictions.  You would need to use the JavaScript API

Comment: When having issues with your accounts or API keys, it would be best that you contact support so that Tech Support agents can take a look internally. Please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/support#contact-maps-support